# Only first image in for loop is shown when added bitmap to layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

**CONTEXT**

I am developing an app where, on a certain moment, a bunch of images are added to the screen. These images are stored on a SQLite database.

---

**HOW IT WORKS**

I have a `for` loop which iterates over each entity that has its own image. Inside the loop, I obtain 
a random position on the screen, and alongside the image of the current entity, I add a custom `View` on that random position.

---

**PROBLEM**

The `for` loop iterates over all data gathered from the database, gets coordinates and images correctly, and no `Exception` is thrown. However, in the main layout, only the image of the first entity is shown, although `addView` is being executed for each one of all entities. The image appearing is only shown once.

---

**SNIPPETS**

Main activity method:

```
// Método que establece el estado inicial de la aplicación
// TODO: Sólo se ve la cereza
private void estadoInicial()
{
    // Recorremos cada fruta obtenida
    for (int i = 0; i < this.contenedorFrutasOriginal.size(); i++)
    {
        // Obtenemos la fruta de la iteración actual
        DTOFruta frutaActual = this.contenedorFrutasOriginal.get(i);

        if (frutaActual.getImagen() != null)
        {
            // Obtenemos una posición aleatoria en la pantalla
            DTOPunto posicionAleatoria = this.objLogicaVistas.ObtenerCoordenadaAleatoria(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay());


            // Creamos una imagen a partir de la fruta
            DTOImagen imagenFruta = new DTOImagen(this, new Paint(),
                                                  frutaActual.getImagen(), posicionAleatoria);

            // Añadimos la imagen a la pantalla
            this.layoutPrincipal.addView(imagenFruta);
        }
    }
}
```

Method that obtains a random coordinate from the screen:

```
// Método que obtiene una coordenada aleatoria en la pantalla recibida
public DTOPunto ObtenerCoordenadaAleatoria(Display pantalla)
{
    // Obtenemos el tamaño de la pantalla
    Point tamanoPantalla = new Point();
    pantalla.getSize(tamanoPantalla);

    // Obtenemos unos valores para los ejes x e y aleatorios
    float xAleatorio = new Random().nextFloat() * tamanoPantalla.x;
    float yAleatorio = new Random().nextFloat() * tamanoPantalla.y;

    // Creamos el punto aleatorio a partir de los valores obtenidos
    return new DTOPunto(xAleatorio, yAleatorio);
}
```

Class for the image getting drawn on the screen:

```
// Clase que representa una vista con una imagen
@SuppressLint("ViewConstructor")
public class DTOImagen extends View
{
// Atributos
private Paint brocha;
private byte[] imagen = null;
private DTOPunto coordenadas;

// Controladores
private boolean arrastrando;


// Propiedades
public Bitmap getImagenBitmap()
{
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(this.imagen, 0, this.imagen.length);
}




// Constructor
public DTOImagen(Context context, Paint brocha, byte[] imagen, DTOPunto coordenadas)
{
    super(context);

    // Obtenemos los datos de la imagen
    this.brocha = brocha;
    if (imagen != null)
    {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }
    this.coordenadas = coordenadas;

    // Asignamos los controladores de la imagen
    this.arrastrando = false;
}




// Método que controla las acciones a realizar al tocar la vista en pantalla
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    // Comprobamos el evento realizado
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
        // Se ha tocado la pantalla
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Obtenemos el hitbox de la vista
            RectF hitbox = this.obtenerHitbox();

            // Comprobamos si se ha tocado dentro del hitbox de la vista
            if (hitbox.contains(event.getX(), event.getY()))
            {
                // La vista se va a arrastrar
                this.arrastrando = true;
            }
            break;

        // Se está arrastrando la vista
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Comprobamos si se está arrastrando la vista
            if (this.arrastrando)
            {
                // Actualizamos las coordenadas de la vista
                this.coordenadas.setX(event.getX());
                this.coordenadas.setY(event.getY());

                // Invalidamos la vista para que se redibuje
                this.invalidate();
            }
            break;

        // Se ha dejado de tocar la vista
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // La imagen se deja de arrastrar
            this.arrastrando = false;
            break;
    }

    return true;
}


// Método que dibuja la vista
@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    // Comprobamos que haya imagen
    if (this.imagen != null)
    {
        // Dibujamos la imagen en las coordenadas correspondientes
        canvas.drawBitmap(this.getImagenBitmap(), this.coordenadas.getX(),
                          this.coordenadas.getY(), this.brocha);
    }
}




// Método que obtiene el hitbox de una imagen
private RectF obtenerHitbox()
{
    // Obtenemos las mitades de la altura y ancho de la imagen
    float ancho = this.getImagenBitmap().getWidth();
    float altura = this.getImagenBitmap().getHeight();

    // Obtenemos las paredes de la vista
    float paredIzquierda = this.coordenadas.getX();
    float paredDerecha = this.coordenadas.getX() + ancho;
    float paredArriba = this.coordenadas.getY();
    float paredAbajo = this.coordenadas.getY() + altura;

    // Hitbox de la vista
    return new RectF(paredIzquierda, paredArriba, paredDerecha, paredAbajo);
}
}
```

`layoutPrincipal` XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".capa_vistas.ActPrincipal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/fondo"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutPrincipal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**DEBUGGING**

The following image shows `layoutPrincipal` children after the `for` loop:
[image: Layout children after adding views]
PD: `DTOPunto` is a class that represents a 2D point, it only has a couple of `float`, for X and Y axis values.
2nd PD: On the last iteration, I found that the layout has all previous images as children, so it looks like those are added correctly.

Comment: Your images are in `DTOFruta frutaActual = this.contenedorFrutasOriginal.get(i);`. But you did not show how you filled that list. Are all images equal there?

Comment: Nope. Each entity on that list has a different image

Comment: Unclear: Does the user only see one image? Or the first image multiple times?

Comment: He only sees the first image once. I will update my question to clarify it

Comment: `private byte[] imagen;`. Initialise to null. As you are checking for null.

Comment: `imagen` is not null in any entity. I get the image from the database when `contenedorFrutasOriginal` is filled, and I checked with debugging that all entities has images.

Comment: If you do a new DTOImagen() then imagen is undefined. Initialise to null.

Comment: I added a null check on the Activity method, both in the question and in my project, thanks for that. The problem remains the same, though

Comment: Please add your xml layout

Comment: You should not add a null check. Thats not what i asked. I said to change `private byte[] imagen;` to `private byte[] imagen = null;`.

Comment: Added. Same issue

Comment: `if ( i < 3 ) continue;` Please add that in the beginning of your for block. Does the user see a different image now?

Comment: I already tried changing initial value of `i` to check different images. Everytime only the image according to the first entity is shown. In your case, the fourth image on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was the layout being a `LinearLayout`. As pointed by @Lena Bru, my views were still there.
However, as I wanted all views being seen without scrolling, I changed my layout to `ConstraintLayout`. The `ImageView`  was removed (that was intended for a background, non-sense when there is an attribute for the root layout), so the XML ended up like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layoutPrincipal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/fondo"
    tools:context=".capa_vistas.ActPrincipal">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now all images are being shown correctly. There is another problem (that only last image added gets dragged), but I will post that in another question now, as it does not relate to current topic.

Comment: Will mark this as answer in 2 days. Can't do so now

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".capa_vistas.ActPrincipal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@mipmap/fondo"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutPrincipal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".capa_vistas.ActPrincipal">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@mipmap/fondo"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layoutPrincipal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Your image is there, it is just taking up the full screen.
When you start scrolling (if this layout is inside a scrollable) you will see that it is there.

Comment: The ImageView is an image that represents the background. I just realized that I did not needed that, so I put the background as an attribute to the layout.

Comment: Also, as I need multiple images to move around (did not specify that on my question 
if I remember correctly), I prefer `ConstraintLayout`